# Python file converted into .exe with pyinstaller stopped working after inserting a few packages

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I try to convert a Python file `.py` into an executable with `PyInstaller`. Until now, it's been working without problems, but since I insert a few packages, I stopped working. I suppose I am open to a few of them:

Here the return error in prompt console:

```
(base) C:\>cd C:\Users\losselj\OneDrive - NAGA Geophysics\Code_Python\tk\program_en_cours

(base) C:\Users\losselj\OneDrive - NAGA Geophysics\Code_Python\tk\program_en_cours>pyinstaller --onefile main.py
2469 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.1
2470 INFO: Python: 3.10.9 (conda)
2487 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
2487 INFO: wrote C:\Users\losselj\OneDrive - NAGA Geophysics\Code_Python\tk\program_en_cours\main.spec
2491 INFO: UPX is not available.
2493 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\losselj\\OneDrive - NAGA '
 'Geophysics\\Code_Python\\tk\\program_en_cours']
3531 INFO: checking Analysis
3531 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
3533 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
3536 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
3545 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
3550 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
8557 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
8557 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib'
9842 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
10002 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
10016 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\python.exe
10174 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\losselj\OneDrive - NAGA Geophysics\Code_Python\tk\program_en_cours\main.py
13120 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
13121 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
23422 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
40432 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
87324 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
105964 INFO: Processing module hooks...
105964 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
105965 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
105970 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
105972 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
106468 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
109192 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
110294 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111145 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111146 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111167 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-llvmlite.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111172 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111172 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111490 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111503 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111523 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numba.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111544 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111617 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111635 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platformdirs.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111636 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-psutil.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111657 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-py.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111981 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111981 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
114152 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
114364 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
114579 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tables.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
114580 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
115199 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
115648 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
115756 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
115756 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115882 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115890 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115891 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115900 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115970 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115980 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
115983 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
116007 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
116008 INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
116306 INFO: Trying determine the default backend as first importable candidate from the list: ['Qt5Agg', 'Gtk3Agg', 'TkAgg', 'WxAgg']
116767 INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['Qt5Agg']
116908 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117212 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117221 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117228 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117229 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
118204 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
118206 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119590 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119601 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119944 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119952 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119977 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119986 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
407 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' because importing 'pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' raised: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'railroad'
122615 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
122617 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
122627 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
122635 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
124469 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
124680 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
124795 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
124991 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125507 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125897 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126013 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126015 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126018 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126022 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126126 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126128 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126129 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
126131 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
568 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'setuptools._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' because importing 'setuptools._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' raised: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'railroad'
129137 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shelve.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
129145 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 27, in <module>
    from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\environment\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.events import EventManager
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\events.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.inspect import safe_getattr
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 18, in <module>
    from sphinx.pycode.ast import ast  # for py36-37
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\pycode\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from zipfile import ZipFile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
132857 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\losselj\OneDrive - NAGA Geophysics\Code_Python\tk\program_en_cours\main.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 487, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 620, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 31, in <module>
    dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
  File "<string>", line 0

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(base) C:\Users\losselj\OneDrive - NAGA Geophysics\Code_Python\tk\program_en_cours>
```

Comment: I forget the package I suppect: 

from tkinter import filedialog

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

Answer (score 4):

As i couldn't comment i write some suggestions here:

```
pyinstaller --clean your_script.py
```

```
pyinstaller --onefile --exclude-module package_name your_script.py
```

And did you tried to remove those packages you suspect and see if it solve it?

Edit:

I ran the libraries you used with pyinstaller and i didn't get any errors. Mostly the problem be solve by `--clean`.

Answer (score 0):

I try with `--clean`, without result. I checked the package `filedialog`, `matplotlib` and `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, there is no problem, however when i add `import pandas as pd`, the conversion failed.